# How to handle a constantly changing schemas and tightly coupled entities (ORM hell)?

Tags: database-design, rdbms, orm

Essentially my team's ended up in a situation where Object A, B, C, D, and E (greatly simplified *sigh*) are different Java objects and each is represented by a single table interconnected with other tables in the DB via foreign keys. Each of the foreign keys MUST be present for the one in the previous chain to exist. We have around 13 different submodules in our application, most of which rely on the shared underlying data in the same database. On top of this, new requirements come in almost daily, requiring that we change large parts of the schema (usually existing parts), our underlying objects, and areas of backend as well. A final nail is that we're being asked to add completely new dimensions to existing data that we never could have anticipated. Now business wants us to rework parts of the data model to better match the UIs representation to better aid in reporting functionality. We're using Hibernate as an ORM framework and primarily use Postgres, though we also need to interface with and have started using multiple SQL Server databases as well.

RDBMS and the relational model has been around for decades, but I'm not sure how something as rigid as the relational model has been able to survive (and continue to be used), even as businesses grow more and more complex. How can better flexibility be achieved and coupling issues be reduced in RDBMS? Our team has tried to target normalization of 3NF, but I believe we might have over-normalized. I'm not looking for a silver bullet answer, as I fear there are numerous issues (though some hints on proper ORM to RDMS design would be helpful).

Having ended up in this ORM/DB hell, my plan to escape would likely be as follows:

1. Keep entities as a database affair. Never pass an entity object between services or to the UI; always deal with DTOs unless the entity is extremely simple or represents a lookup table. By passing DTOs around, we can avoid tightly coupling interoperating services in the backend and frontend with our data layer.
2. Check particular pain points in the data model and think of how we can overcome them.

   - One example is user access. Essentially, the system works by checking a combination of values that exist on multiple entities against the combinations a user has access to. Having to add new columns to this combination is difficult because it requires a refactor of every query in the entire system (since join conditions now change)--not to mention special exceptions for certain people/management levels.
   - Maybe a tag system would work here? Idk just my thoughts.

I'd like to hear from the community in general. I cannot imagine my team is alone in facing these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fair, but it's not the norm that one's schema changes so significantly with such great frequency, at least with the general details you've provided. I'm sure you're not the only one either though. I will say, having worked in the Financial Tech industry, where everything is needed *yesterday*, even our schema didn't change so much as you've described your's does. It would probably be helpful to qualify your data a little better with the type of industry, objects at play, etc, to some degree, so someone with topically relevant experience may be able to comment.

> Having ended up in this ORM/DB hell, my plan to escape would likely be as follows:
>
> Keep entities as a database affair. Never pass an entity object between services or to the UI; always deal with DTOs unless the entity is extremely simple or represents a lookup table.

DTOs are usually a good way to abstract away the objects that are consumed in the application vs the data objects that live in the database, and can help minimize errors when future schema changes occur. But do keep in mind it's generally more work to manage the implementation of a DTO in addition to the database object, especially when you want to propagate schema changes to the application. So if your problem is keeping up with the workload of the frequency for which your schema changes, DTOs won't necessarily make it less work for you to implement those changes, and in fact will generally make it more work.

> Check particular pain points in the data model and think of how we can overcome them.
>
> One example is user access. Essentially, the system works by checking a combination of values that exist on multiple entities against the combinations a user has access to.

If I understand you correctly, are you saying you manage users' data access based on specific data attributes for that user in the database? If so, there are features of modern database systems that help you manage this.

In SQL Server this is known as [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver16) and in PostgreSQL it's called [Row Security Policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). These features make management of data security a lot easier, because you no longer need to manage the changes to predicates (i.e. `JOIN` conditions) directly, everywhere they're used. Rather, you define the conditional logic once, and provide the list of entities that should be bound by those data security rules. As the logic evolves over time, you only need to update the logic in one place, inside the data security policy itself.

Comment: I had no idea about the row-level security features these DBs provide. Thank you! I will definitely check into those. I know the DTOs would be more work, but right now the tight coupling between our services and the database structure is preventing us from design changes and rapidly implementing new feature requests.

Comment: The issues we're experiencing are partly company-related. Business has been using Excel alone for decades, having different levels of management handle different excel workbooks where the structure of data is irrelevant. If a new column is needed, they just make it up and it eventually propagates to other managers. The company does use DBs, but to my understanding they just upload excel sheets to a DB and call it a day. Part of my project's goal is to try to reduce the dependency on Excel that the company has while providing good reporting functionality. Company is massive (~300K) employees.

Comment: @ElderFuthark No problem! When you say "*preventing us from design changes*", I assume that's because you are unsure of what in the application layer can break without being updated. This comes down the technology you're using and the implementation you've chosen. The ORMs I work with (though I work in the Microsoft stack, so C# and .NET world) allow certain schema changes in the database layer to occur without affecting the auto-generated objects in the application layer. Alternatively, some people abstract their data objects with Views and Procedures, but that's similar in concept to DTOs.